# MIS capacitors discharge

Tags: capacitor, semiconductors

Do MIS Capacitors discharge completely or only partially due to lack of free charges?

Inside the semiconductor there is a depletion region with no mobile charge carriers so they wouldnt move to the lower potential right?

Comment: Dielectric absorption being a non-ideal effect, wouldn't all real capacitors suffer from it?

Comment: is this yes or no?

Comment: Well, your question seems to be implying that capacitors not discharging all the way is not typical of capacitors, when it's actually the norm, It's just the degree to which it varies.

Comment: metal metal capacitors are not discharged all the way?>

Comment: I wouldn't expect them to just because others capacitors don't either and the effect has more to do with the dielectric than the actual plates.

Answer (score 0):

There is not **always** a depletion region...that only occurs if you have an interface between a P-type region and an N-type region. If the semiconductor is heavily and uniformly doped then it will behave pretty much as would a conductor, with no depletion region to interfere with the behavior of the capacitor.

Comment: But if we have p type and we connect the capacitor to the battery like reverse bias then wont we have inside the p type an n type region close to the insulator a depletion region below that n type region and then a normal p type region(assuming charged capacitor).

Comment: I don't think this would occur for a **heavily doped** semiconductor under reasonable conditions. If the semiconductor is P-type, where would the excess electrons come from to make an inversion layer? In a transistor they would come from the N-type source.